# How to safely "pop-front" from std::map without extra copy?

Tags: c++, stl

I have a `std::map` object.

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> m;

m.insert({ "abcd", "foo" });
m.insert({ "1234", "bar" });
```

and I want to get and remove the first element, like:

```
auto iter = m.begin();
auto [key, value] = std::move(*iter);
m.erase(iter);
do_something_with(key, value);
```

Is this considered safe?
(Moving from the iterator should make the key an empty string, which makes the `m` an invalid map.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this considered safe?

On the condition that the map isn't empty, yes.

**However**, note that the key will be a deep copy; not moved one. This is because the the key of the map element is const.

> How to safely “pop-front” from std::map without extra copy?

It is possible to move from the key too, if you use the `extract` member function:

```
auto handle = m.extract(m.begin());
// if you need separate objects:
auto key = std::move(handle.key());
auto mapped = std::move(handle.mapped());
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`std::map::extract`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/extract) like this:

```
auto nh = m.extract(m.begin());
```

and then use the key and value like this:

```
do_something(nh.key(), nh.mapped());
```

This has the needed property that no extra copies are made.

Answer (score 1):

Use std map extract.  Using the resulting node handle, move the key/value to your key/value variables.

Prior to std map extract, this isn't fully possible.  std map extract was added to let you do this, and similar operations like splicing maps.